# Handling null pointer exception

Tags: java

I am getting NullPointerException in the code.I want to handle it.
In the following code i have specified the line in which the null pointer exception occurs.

```
 public static void mapPcm16bitLittleEndian2Float(final byte[] pcm16bitBytes,
            final int offsetInput,
            final float[] samples,
            final int offsetOutput,
            final int length) {
        if (pcm16bitBytes.length - offsetInput < 2 * length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient Samples to convert to floats");
        }
        if (samples.length - offsetOutput < length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient float buffer to convert the samples");// Getting null pointer exception here.
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            samples[offsetOutput + i] = ((pcm16bitBytes[offsetInput + 2 * i] & 0xff) | (pcm16bitBytes[offsetInput + 2 * i + 1] << 8)); // no & 0xff at the end to keep the sign
        }


and

 public boolean processData(final byte[] data,
            final int offset,
            final int len) {
        // converty raw bytes into float samples
        mapPcm16bitLittleEndian2Float(data, offset, rawData, 0, len / 2);// getting null pointer exception
        // encode the bitstream
        return processData(rawData, len / 2);
    }
```

Please help me getting out of this.

Comment: debug and check the values of your variable

Comment: Post the full stack trace. The indicated line is probably one frame to early, since no pointer access happens right there, but in the body of the called method.

Answer (score 1):

One of the `array`s you are referencing is `null`, hence referencing its `length` property will throw a `NullPointerException`.

You should check for both of your `array`s being null (`== null`) to handle this `Exception`, and act accordingly (e.g. rethrow an `IllegalArgumentException`).

Comment: @ Mena Thanks for the above coding.it works.getting null pointer exception in public boolean processData(final float[] data, final int numSamples) { int numSamplesRequired = channels * frameSize; if (numSamples != numSamplesRequired) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("SpeexEncoder requires " + numSamplesRequired + " samples to process a Frame, not " + numSamples ); } // encode the bitstream if (channels==2) { Stereo.encode(bits, data, frameSize); } encoder.encode(bits, data); return true; } –

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Mena, null pointer check is a must.

Hope the below code snippet helps :

```
 public static void mapPcm16bitLittleEndian2Float(final byte[] pcm16bitBytes,
                final int offsetInput,
                final float[] samples,
                final int offsetOutput,
                final int length) {


            if(pcm16bitBytes != null && pcm16bitBytes.length >0 && samples != null && samples.length >0){
                System.out.println("If the arrays are null ,should not enter this block");
                if (pcm16bitBytes.length - offsetInput < 2 * length) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient Samples to convert to floats");
                }
                if (samples.length - offsetOutput < length) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient float buffer to convert the samples");// Getting null pointer exception here.
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    samples[offsetOutput + i] = ((pcm16bitBytes[offsetInput + 2 * i] & 0xff) | (pcm16bitBytes[offsetInput + 2 * i + 1] << 8)); // no & 0xff at the end to keep the sign
                }


            }
        }
```

Regards,Madhu

Comment: @ Madhu Bose Thanks for the above coding.it works.getting null pointer exception in public boolean processData(final float[] data, final int numSamples)
  {
    int numSamplesRequired = channels * frameSize;
    if (numSamples != numSamplesRequired) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("SpeexEncoder requires " + numSamplesRequired + " samples to process a Frame, not " + numSamples );
    }
    // encode the bitstream
    if (channels==2) {
      Stereo.encode(bits, data, frameSize);
    }
    encoder.encode(bits, data);
    return true;
  }

Comment: Thanks user3912813, Am glad it helped  :) .Request you to accept my answer .

Comment: @ Madhu Bose Please help me with previous coding.. Please

Comment: Not getting you ? previous coding??

Comment: Are you taking about the below issue which you are facing?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181006/handling-arraystoreexception